# Post Jenkins upgrade dont get jobs drop down menu from Dashboard

Tags: jenkins, dashboard

I have upgraded Jenkins from 1.639 to 2.60 by replacing the WAR file on the windows server.
However following this, on the jenkins job view i no longer get the drop down menu for some of the jobs
In some cases I can get the drop down menu from the All jobs view but not another specific view tab. But in other cases the drop down menu does not appear on the All view or any other tab the job is on. In all cases this worked prior to upgrade.
This does not seem to be related to thee manage of old data or for how recent a job has been run.

Answer (score 0):

Transpires it was a browser compatibility issue. I had been using Chrome 21 but when I swapped and used IE 11 the drop down menus were consistently available on the upgraded 2.60 versions